# split file into multiple files based on appearance of name in first column

Tags: awk, split

How to split a file.txt into subfiles, where each file has a continues appearance of XX in file.txt? Such as print lines start with XX into file1.txt and if next line is not XX close file1.txt and open file2.txt for next appearance of XX.

Input file: file.txt

```
some header information
XX 123 456 abc
XX 234 567 def
XX 456 345 ghi
END
XX 345 654 ijk
XX 567 789 klm
XX 678 asd mno
XX 567 thy mnb
YY 123 dft fty
XX 456 tfg tyg 
XX 456 thu gtr 
PAGE2
XX 345 dcf try
```

Desired output:

file1.txt

```
XX 123 456 abc
XX 234 567 def
XX 456 345 ghi
```

file2.txt

```
XX 345 654 ijk
XX 567 789 klm
XX 678 asd mno
XX 567 thy mnb
```

file3.txt

```
XX 456 tfg tyg 
XX 456 thu gtr
```

file4.txt

```
XX 345 dcf try
```

Comment: You will likely get a much more friendly reception and much better help here if you show what code you have tried so far and describe what problems you were having with it. Without code, your question looks like a request for free consulting and there are many people here who don't like that.

Comment: StackOverflow is about helping people fix their existing programming code. Edit your Q to show  your best attempt at coding a solution to your problem. Sorry, but requests for tutorials, research, tools, recommendations, libraries, and code are off-topic.  ***Please*** read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ,   https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour] (https://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck

Comment: I understand it, I should have shown the commands I tried to get desired output. Thanks for commenting, I will keep this in mind next time.

Answer (score 4):

Using `awk`, one-liner:

```
$ awk '!/^XX/{if(f)close(f);f=sprintf("file%d.txt",++n);next}{print >f}' infile
```

**Explanation:**

```
awk '!/^XX/{                          # if line/record/row does not start with XX
         if(f)                        # if variable f was set before
            close(f);                 # close file 
         f=sprintf("file%d.txt",++n); # pre increment variable n, generate new file name
         next                         # go to next line
      }
      {
         print >f                     # Records starts with XX will be
                                      # written to file defined in variable f
      }
     ' infile
```

Test Results:

***Input:***

```
$ cat infile
some header information
XX 123 456 abc
XX 234 567 def
XX 456 345 ghi
END
XX 345 654 ijk
XX 567 789 klm
XX 678 asd mno
XX 567 thy mnb
YY 123 dft fty
XX 456 tfg tyg 
XX 456 thu gtr 
PAGE2
XX 345 dcf try
```

***Output:***

```
$ cat file1.txt 
XX 123 456 abc
XX 234 567 def
XX 456 345 ghi

$ cat file2.txt 
XX 345 654 ijk
XX 567 789 klm
XX 678 asd mno
XX 567 thy mnb

$ cat file3.txt 
XX 456 tfg tyg 
XX 456 thu gtr 

$ cat file4.txt 
XX 345 dcf try
```

**For comment:**

> if there are too many lines in header information of the input file,
>   the output file name starts with a bigger number. How can I start the
>   output file from ouput1.out and so on?

```
awk '/^XX/{if(!w)f=sprintf("file%d.txt",++n);w=1;print >f;next}{close(f);w=0}' infile
```

**Explanation:**

```
awk '/^XX/{                             # if line starts with XX
        if(!w)                          # if negate of w is true
           f=sprintf("file%d.txt",++n); # pre increment n, and set up variable f 
        w=1;                            # set variable w = 1
        print >f;                       # write record/row/line to file
        next                            # go to next line
     }
     {                                  # for which does not start with XXX  
        close(f);                       # close file
        w=0                             # set w = 0, (so that for next line with XX use newfile)
     }
    ' infile
```

**Test Results - for comment :**

Input-modified :

```
$ cat infile 
some header information
some header2
some header 3
XX 123 456 abc
XX 234 567 def
XX 456 345 ghi
END
some more extra
wxxasa
extrasa
XX 345 654 ijk
XX 567 789 klm
XX 678 asd mno
XX 567 thy mnb
YY 123 dft fty
XX 456 tfg tyg 
XX 456 thu gtr 
PAGE2
XX 345 dcf try
```

Execution:

```
$ awk '/^XX/{if(!w)f=sprintf("file%d.txt",++n); w=1;  print >f;next}{close(f); w=0}' infile
```

Files generated:

```
$ ls *.txt -1
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
file4.txt
```

Contents of each file:

```
$ for i in *.txt; do echo "File: $i"; cat $i; done
File: file1.txt
XX 123 456 abc
XX 234 567 def
XX 456 345 ghi
File: file2.txt
XX 345 654 ijk
XX 567 789 klm
XX 678 asd mno
XX 567 thy mnb
File: file3.txt
XX 456 tfg tyg 
XX 456 thu gtr 
File: file4.txt
XX 345 dcf try
```

Comment: Nice answer, +1! Could you add some explanations about your command?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Allan Thanks, added explanation

Comment: @AkshayHegde Thanks for the answer with explanation. if there are too many lines in header information of the input file, the output file name starts with a bigger number. How can I start the output file from ouput1.out and so on?

Comment: @user3132983 : see my edit `awk '/^XX/{if(!w)f=sprintf("file%d.txt",++n);w=1;print >f;next}{close(f);w=0}' infile`

Comment: @AkshayHegde Awesome..! It works perfectly. I appreciate your kind help. One more thing, If I iterate it over a number of input files, how to print output file name same as input file name ends with increment numbers? I know I can get the input file name with `{file=FILENAME;sub(".txt","",file)}` but how to include it within above one-liner command?

Comment: @user3132983 make `FNR==1{file=FILENAME;sub(".txt","",file);}` and in  other block `f=sprintf("%s-%d.txt",file, ++n);`

Answer (score 1):

Following `awk` may also help you in same.

```
awk '!/^XX/{delete a[XX];if("file"val".txt"){close("file"val".txt")};next} FNR>1 && !a[XX]++{val++} /^XX/{print > "file"val".txt"}' Input_file
```

it will create 4 output files as follows.

```
-rw-rw-r--  1 singh singh   15 Jan 17 22:29 file4.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 singh singh   32 Jan 17 22:29 file3.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 singh singh   60 Jan 17 22:29 file2.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 singh singh   45 Jan 17 22:29 file1.txt
```

Above is written and tested in GNU `awk` in case you don't have GNU `awk` you could change from `delete a[XX]` to `for(num in a){delete a[num]}` too. I will also add explanation too now for same.

***EDIT:*** Adding a non-one liner form of solution along with explanation too here.

```
awk '
!/^XX/{                    ##Checking condition here if a line is NOT starting from string XX then do following:
  delete a[XX];            ##delete the array named a content whose index is string XX here. This is to make sure XX count is getting increased only once not in all occurrences of string XX.
  if("file"val".txt"){     ##Checking here if a file named "file"val".txt" is opened here, if yes then close it so that we could avoid the problem of too many files opened here.
    close("file"val".txt") ##closing the file named "file"val",txt" here.
}
  next                     ##next is awk out of the box keyword which will skip all further statements from cursor current position and awk will read next line and start executing the statement from starting again.
}
FNR>1 && !a[XX]++{         ##Checking condition here if line number is greater than 1 and array a value with index of string XX is NULL then do following:
  val++;                   ##Increasing the value of variable named val here with 1 each time cursor comes in here.
}
/^XX/{                     ##Checking condition here if a line is starting from string XX here then do following:
  print > "file"val".txt"  ##Printing the current line into variable "file"val".txt" which is actually the output file name like file1.txt, file2.txt etc etc..
}
'  Input_file             ##Mentioning the Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following awk command to process the file and generate output files:

```
awk 'BEGIN{file_cmpt=1}{if($1=="XX"){print $0 > "output"file_cmpt".out";}else{file_cmpt++}}' input.txt
```

**explanation**:

- `BEGIN{file_cmpt=1}` initial the file counter to 1
- `{if($1=="XX"){print $0 > "output"file_cmpt".out";}` if the first column is `XX` you print it to the current file
- `else{file_cmpt++}` if one line first field is different then `XX` then you print it to another file

**test on your input file:**

[image]

if you have some header information at the top of your input file you can use the following `awk` command:

```
awk 'BEGIN{file_cmpt=1;in_header=1}{if($1=="XX"){print $0 > "output"file_cmpt".out";in_header=0}else{if(!in_header){file_cmpt++}}}' input.txt
```

The only change is that I added a in_header test condition before incrementing the file counter. (we suppose that initially we are in the header part of the file and as soon as we meet the first occurrence of `XX`we set the value of this to 0 and we can start incrementing the counter as soon as we reach a line where the first field is not equal to `XX`.

**tested on the following input:**

[image]

Comment: I tried this and it works. What I found if there are too many lines in header information of the input file, the output file name (`"output"file_cmpt".out"`)  start with a bigger number. How can I start the output file from `ouput1.out` and so on?

Comment: let me fix this for you! I will filter out the header